# Multiline figure caption centering

Tags: captions, horizontal-alignment

How to center a figure caption that's too long for a single line? Or at least, make the text in other lines line-up with text after "Slika 1:". It currently looks like this [image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}% or e.g. [format=hang]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{This caption is very long---in fact, it is so long that it doesn't fit on one line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in `beamer`, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about beamer, but I had a strange document class that also refused to give the correct output with `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}` and I simply used `\\\centering` in the caption text to get the desired output.